# Gson data storing and retrieving. Storing as String, retrieving as integer

Tags: java, arrays, string, gson, parseint

In my datastorage class I have used Gson to save String data called `setTeam` and to retrieve data called `getTeam`

```
public class DataStorage {
        private static final String TEAM = "Teams";
        private static final String TEAM_INFO = "teaminfo";
        private static Gson gson = new Gson();


        public static void setTeam(MainActivity context, Collection<User> teams) {
            String usersJson = gson.toJson(teams);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(TEAM_INFO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString(TEAM, usersJson);
            editor.apply();
        }

        public static ArrayList<User> getTeam(Context context){
            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(TEAM_INFO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String usersJson = prefs.getString(TEAM, "[]");
            return gson.fromJson(usersJson, new TypeToken<ArrayList<User>>(){}.getType());
        }

    }
```

Then I made a class called `User` for each team that is saved in my json database. So for each `setTeam` there is a `teamName`  `gameWon` and `gameLost`

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private String teamName;
    private int gameWon;
    private int gameLost;

    public void setName(String name) {this.teamName = name;}
    public String getName() {return teamName;}

    public void setGameWon(int wonHome){this.gameWon = wonHome;}
    public int getGameWon(){return gameWon;}

    public void setGameLost (int gameLoss){this.gameLost = gameLoss;}
    public int getGameLost(){return gameLost;}
}
```

In the main activity I have created a Double String `ArrayList` which includes some numbers.

```
private final String[][] dataTeams = new String[30][3];
```

So in the dataTeams double Array there are 30 teams with their gameWon and gameLost. gameWon and gameLost are number strings.

So now I am trying to save whatever in the dataTeams into the Json database.

```
User c = new User();
c.setName(dataTeams[i][0]);
c.setGameWon(Integer.parseInt(dataTeams[i][2]));
c.setGameLost(Integer.parseInt(dataTeams[i][3]));

teams.add(c);
DataStorage.setTeam(this, teams);
```

Which I have done successfully, however when I retrieve the data;

```
ArrayList<User> users = DataStorage.getTeam(this);
        String [] teams = new String[30];
        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            teams[i] = users.get(i).getName() + "  W:" + users.get(i).getGameWon() + " L:" + users.get(i).getGameLost();
        }
```

The getName is correct for all the teams, however their getGameWon and getGameLost are all 0s and that is not what is in the double Array `dataTeams`

So now I am stuck between whether the Json class I made `DataStorage` did not save the Strings when I parsed to int

```
c.setGameWon(Integer.parseInt(dataTeams[i][2]));
c.setGameLost(Integer.parseInt(dataTeams[i][3]));
```

Or I am parsing the integer wrong.

The data in the dataTeam are

```
Team    W   L   
Atlanta     60  22  
Boston      40  42  
Brooklyn    38  44  
Charlotte   33  49
Chicago     50  32  
Cleveland   53  29  
Dallas      50  32  
Denver      30  52  
Detroit     32  50  
Golden State 67 15  
Houston     56  26  
Indiana     38  44  
L.A. Clippers   56  26  
L.A. Lakers     21  61  
Memphis     55  27  
Miami       37  45  
Milwaukee   41  41  
Minnesota   16  66  
New Orleans 45  37  
New York    17  65  
Oklahoma City   45  37  
Orlando     25  57  
Philadelphia    18  64  
Phoenix     39  43  
Portland    51  31  
Sacramento  29  53  
San Antonio 55  27  
Toronto     49  33  
Utah        38  44  
Washington  46  36
```

Comment: Can you share your JSON data?

Comment: @PhilipRollins Of course, I have added it to the bottom

Comment: I think your data is not JSON, it's a tsv (tab separated values). So you can use some CSV library to read it efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration:

```
private final String[][] dataTeams = new String[30][3];
```

Your setting data logic:

```
c.setGameWon(Integer.parseInt(dataTeams[i][2]));  // << [i][1]
c.setGameLost(Integer.parseInt(dataTeams[i][3]));  // << [i][2]
```

May be incorrect index cause the error occurred.